# Type checking based on other variable in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typeguards

Is it possible in TypeScript to have a variable that indicates the type of other variables?
Ultimately I would like to only check one variable `stateIndicator` that is dependend on other variables to assume their types.

```js
type A = {prop1: string}
type B = {prop2: number}

function isA(x: A | B): x is A {
  return (x as A).prop1 !== undefined
}

function foo1(data: A | B) {
  const stateIndicator = isA(data);
  if (stateIndicator) {
    // this is fine
    const myString: string = data.prop1;
  }
}

function foo2(data: A | B) {
  const stateIndicator = isA(data) ? "stateA" : "stateB";
  if (stateIndicator === "stateA") {
    // here unless I check if isA(data) or do "data as A" the data.prop1 shows error 
    // Property 'prop1' does not exist on type 'B'
    const myString: string = data.prop1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your `foo1` is explicitly supported as an [aliased boolean condition](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#control-flow-analysis-of-aliased-conditions-and-discriminants) but there's no support for the compiler "transferring" the condition to the logical results of some expression as you're doing in `foo2`.  (more)

Comment: (continued)  There have been similar-ish requests, like at [ms/TS#49583](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/49583), but nothing implemented yet.  I'd recommend working *with* the type system instead of against it, and turn your types into a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/mxx8Gm). Does this fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; it not, what am I missing?

Comment: It's very similar with discriminated union in your example and in `foo2` checking `data.stateIndicator` instead of calling `isA()` does exact the same. I just came up with spreading all states to constants instead of keeping one as string like [here](http://tsplay.dev/mZvQam), but then trying to organize it in object gives the same error... And I was aiming for more complex state indicators, but it seems that having them all as seperate "const" is the way

Comment: So does that mean I should or should not write up an answer (with links to sources)?

Comment: would be cool to know details why this can't be like in foo2

Comment:  Sorry for my confusion, but: I *think* you're saying "yes I'd like to see your answer written up" but you haven't said this explicitly. And I could *also* interpret what you said as "I would rather have someone provide details that you haven't mentioned so I wouldn't accept your answer if you wrote one."  At this point, could you please reply with either an explicit "yes, please write up your answer" or "no, your answer would not suffice"? I just want there to be no ambiguity before I proceed, because I've been wrong before when making such assumptions.

Comment: yes, please write up your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, what you're looking for isn't possible in TypeScript.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#46915](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/46915) for a canonical answer.

---

In general, the TypeScript compiler cannot track all possible logical consequences of your code. That is, it doesn't do *counterfactual reasoning* like "in the body of `foo2()`, if `stateIndicator` is `"stateA"` that must mean `isA(data)` returned `true`, since if had returned `false` then `stateIndicator` would be `"stateB"` which is not equal to `"stateA"` and there's no other way that `stateIndicator` could be `"stateA"`.  So therefore `data` must be an `A`".  It would be too expensive to do something like that in general.

For most cases any check you perform on one variable (like `stateIndicator`) will, at most, affect the apparent type of that variable itself, and not other variables whose history might be entangled with it.  So `stateIndicator === "stateA"` [narrows](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#equality-narrowing) `stateIndicator` itself, but nothing else.  Even checking the property of an object will generally only affect the apparent type of that property, and not the apparent type of the parent object, unless the parent object is of a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) type and the property checked is its discriminant.

There are a few cases where something like this does happen.  [TypeScript 4.4 introduced control flow analysis of *aliased* conditions and discriminants](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#control-flow-analysis-of-aliased-conditions-and-discriminants).  That means if you assign the `boolean` result of a yes-no type guard to a `const`, or assign the discriminant property of a discriminated union to a `const`, then subsequent checks of that `const` will narrow the type of the related variable.  This is what lets your `foo1` implementation work; `stateIndicator` is an aliased type guard `boolean`.  But in `foo2`, `stateIndicator` is neither an alias of a `boolean` guard check, nor an alias of a discriminant property of a discriminated union.  So no narrowing occurs.

---

Since what you're trying to do isn't possible you will have to work around it.  In general the cleanest and most well-supported approach is to make the union into a discriminated union by adding a discriminant property to each member, and then checking the discriminant:

```
type A = { stateIndicator: "stateA", prop1: string }
type B = { stateIndicator: "stateB", prop2: number }

function foo(data: A | B) {
    if (data.stateIndicator === "stateA") {
        const myString: string = data.prop1;
    } else {
        const myNumber: number = data.prop2;
    }
}
```

But obviously your use cases will drive the choice of workaround.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeUDOwCGwIEkB2AJgJYDGWA9gE4BcUAROlhDHQDRRiXlgCMt6lIngDmUAL4BYAFChIUAEIJkaTNnzEywKrQaqI8thy5gATLTwBXALYAjCJXHTpAMwt4SwIuTxRn5cgAUBFgYtHAAPgoAlMjSUPFQRM5QQSEAdIxqhKQUDvD59JnMdDFIcQkVJN7oUFYgAMrAgiL8TUKiiMGYaZzcPADc5fFiUBAANqjQZVIVldXAtSAActZ2NFCWtvZKXRg9xiaDMwmSUqfSQA)